# Render countdowns on each flat list item

Tags: reactjs, performance, firebase, react-native

I'm doing an auctions app with react-native and Firebase, I'm using a `FlatList` to render each auction component.

On each auction component want to show a countdown with the reminder time, I'm retrieving the end date of the auction from Firebase.

But if I update the state every second, of each of my auction components my app  gets really slow.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: If you want the countdown to be refreshed at 1-sec intervals, then you have to update the state to re-render every 1-sec. This shouldn't cause too much of a performance issue though if you are using a FlatList. Your performance bottleneck likely lies with some other problem.

Comment: That's where React shines! Reconciliation concept is all about this, unless your component tag structures are not altered there is practically no performance overhead. It's more like just updating the element attributes.

Comment: No problem if I have many intervals running one for each of my comopents in the flat list? Because the app works perfectly when I'm not using the coundes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have many intervals running one for each of my components in the flat list

You can move the timer to the component with `FlatList` so that you only have one timer.

Also make sure the interval is set in `componentDidMount` and cleared in `componentWillUnmount`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    timeElapsed: 0,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interavl = setInterval(
      () => this.setState((prev) => ({ timeElapsed: prev.timeElapsed + 1 })),
      1000,
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  render() {
    return <FlatList renderItem={() => <Child timeElapsed={this.state.timeElapsed} />} />;
  }
}

const Child = (props) => <Text>{props.timeRemaining - props.timeElapsed}</Text>;
```